# Get integer values in CSS/SCSS

Tags: html, css

I have two containers side by side. The left one contains a THREE.js canvas which doesn't allow for decimal size values.
The left container should take up about 80% of the viewport width and right should take the rest of the space.

Is there a way to floor the left containers width in CSS/SCSS?
I tried to use `width:floor(80%);` but that doesn't seem to do anything.

My SCSS file:

```
.tree-view {
  //width: floor(80%);
  width: 80%;
  float:left;
  display: flex;
}
.data-view {
  //width: ceil(20%);
  width: 20%;
  float:right;
  display: flex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out, that canvas allows for decimal size values. The problem was that `getBoundingClientRect()` doesn't give me the exact size of the the container, despite no paddings or margins were used.

For the time being I set the canvas size to `window.innerWidth * 0.8`.